# How to style jPanelMenu?

Tags: jquery, css

I understand jPanelMenu (http://jpanelmenu.com) is meant to be easily styled and customized.

I've tried adding a jPanelMenu-panel class to the HTML like so:

```
<div class="section group jPanelMenu-panel">       
     <div class="menu-trigger">Click Me</div>
     <ul id="menu" style="display: none;">
         <li><a href="/">Overview</a></li>
         <li><a href="#usage">Usage</a></li>
         <li><a href="#inner-workings">Inner-Workings</a></li>
         <li><a href="#animation">Animation</a></li>
         <li><a href="#options">Options</a></li>
         <li><a href="#api">API</a></li>
         <li><a href="#tips">Tips &amp; Examples</a></li>
         <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
     </ul>                                
</div>
```

And adding a .jPanelMenu-panel class to the CSS like so:

```
.jPanelMenu-panel {
    background-color: black;
}
```

To see if anything changes.  I have tried adding my own classes to see if anything at all changes.

The good news is that I have the latest version of jQuery thanks to h5bp and I have included the following tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jpanelmenu.js"</script>
```

Correctly since the slider menu does work on my page.  I click on the "Click Me" text and the slider menu appears as expected, with no styling at all.

My goal is to have styles working similar to the menu on jpanelmenu.com and to go from there.

I know this should be a simple thing, but I am lost.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the > on the end of the opening `<script>` tag .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jpanelmenu.js"></script>
------------------------------------------------------------^
```

You're right though as the menu is working as expected your browser is probably automatically fixing this issues itself... what i think the problem might be is if the default styling is overriding the extra styling you are adding in... try changing the main CSS file.

**EDIT**

You are right with your snippet of CSS below

```
.jPanelMenu-panel {
    background-color: black;
}
```

However this might be being overidden in the default CSS file you might have already linked (you'll be able to see this when use a web inspector). If so try changing the styling in this main file.

Comment: Thank you for that, however it hasn't answered the question in regards to styling the menu.  I do appreciate the heads up and gave a +1 for that, but I am really dying to know how to style jQuery plugins like this.  If you could point me in the right direction I am willing to read anything and everything. I do have a basic understanding of javascript and jQuery (i.e. objects, methods, basic syntax for things like anonymous functions, the document.ready method.  I just, for the life of me, can't figure out how to style this menu!

Comment: I am wondering, should I be accessing any special classes created by the jPanelMenu plugin or should I be creating styles in css and placing them somewhere special? I need to know the basic idea of how to style something like this before I can debug it.

Comment: Great.  I tried applying a background-color to the <ul> and that works like a charm. So I believe you are right, something is being over-ridden.  I will look into this and I am usually pretty decent at solving css problems, I guess I got scared when jQuery was added.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

jPanelMenu uses [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) (a css pre-processor) for styling. In the latest version of jPanelMenu (1.3.0) there is a folder called "Sass" where you can find various .scss files. The ones that their filename begins with an underscore are called partials, and they are imported in the style.**scss** file, which later gets compiled to style.**css** (the one that is linked to your html file)

As you can see from the partial filenames, each one represents something like "footer", "content", "jPanelMenu" "reset". You can simply edit those partials and link the generated style.css to your html.

For more information about sass, check the link I provided above and also the [Sass Reference](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html). If you're familiar with CSS, it shouldn't be hard to get your head around it.

Have fun experimenting and styling your jPanelMenu!